# Reading two integers at the end of text

Tags: c#, asp.net, regex

I am getting values from the form in the following format:

```
text 2234-7755
```

What i want to do is read first four integers than the last four integer values separately. 
Please let me know how can i read that. Thanks

Comment: Split by space, take second group, and split by `-`? What have you tried so far?

Comment: (\d+) this will give you two groups.

Comment: Does the number always have 8 digits separated by `-`?

Comment: Just to be quite clear: You want two integer: 2234, and 7755, right? Not eight different integers?

Comment: When you say "text", is that the name of the variable, or do you receive a string that has some text in it, followed by that number pattern at the end?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the number is always at the end, has 8 digits and is separated by `-` you don't need regex:

```
string number = text.Substring(text.Length - 9);
string[] both = number.Split('-');
int firstNum, secondNum;
if (both.Length == 2 
    && int.TryParse(both[0], out firstNum) 
    && int.TryParse(both[1], out secondNum))
{
    Console.Write("First number is: {0}\r\nSecond number is: {1}", firstNum, secondNum);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
string[] nums = text.Split("-");
int num1 = Convert.ToInt32(nums[0]);
int num2 = Convert.ToInt32(nums[1]);
```

If you want to be safer, you can use `int.TryParse`

Comment: Probable `nums[2] will throw index out of rage exception`

Comment: It's `nums[0]` and `nums[1]`

Comment: @Șhȇkhaṝ woops, see that now, fixed

Answer (score 0):

use split function and get the first value.
A [link](http://www.dotnetperls.com/split) for the same

```
  var original="2234-7755";
  var intArray = original.Split("-");

  int part1 = Convert.ToInt32(intArray[0]);
  int part2 = Convert.ToInt32(intArray[1]);
```

You can also use [Int32.TryParse](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f02979c7(v=vs.110).aspx) method if you want more control.

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking  for something like this?

```
string text = "text 2234-7755";

var matches = Regex.Matches(text, @"(\d+)");
if (matches.Count == 2)
{
    int value1 = Convert.ToInt32(matches[0].Groups[1].Value);
    int value2 = Convert.ToInt32(matches[1].Groups[1].Value);
}
```

Comment: Initially I thought RegEx was overkill, but if the OP clarifies what text could be in "text", then it may be useful.